# Internal hard disk partitions (sda2) not showing in android system

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, mount, partitions, android-x86, disk-drive

I have a x86 system (Asus Eee Pc)having hard disk of 232 GB, in which 4 GB allocated for Android and rest I don't know where it is gone. If I open super user and running this command in android terminal: `cat /proc/partitions` I get following result:

```
Block_Size(232Gb) sda
Block_Size(4Gb) sda1
Block_Size(rest) sda2
```

This shows there are two partitions (`sda1`, `sda2`) of total 1 drive (`sda`). 
Android is installed in `sda1` and seen in it's file system. But `sda2` data is invisible.
When i **run mount command** , we get :

- rootfs /rootfs rw 0 0
- proc /proc proc rw ,relatime 0 0
- /dev/sda1 /mnt ext3 rw,relatime,error=continue,barrier=0,data=writeback 0 0
- few lines ....
  But nothing about sda2 .

I also try #busybox fdisk -l /dev/block/sda

```
   Device Boot     start   End     Blocks  Id  System
```

- /dev/block/sda1       1     528   4241128+  83  Linux
- /dev/block/sda2      529   30396  23914716  83  Linux
- /dev/block/sda3     30397  30402   42714    ef  EFI(FAT-12/16/32)

And when i run

-#busybox fdisk -l /dev/block/sda2
result is :
 - doesn't contain a valid partition table .

How can I mount this drive in android? I just want to access and view the `sda2` storage drive.

Comment: Not the final answer, but did you try the `mount` command (without options) in the same place? It should show you what partitions are mounted in the system and where. It's quite possible `sda2` might be listed there, which makes the second part of your question (how to mount it) obsolete, and you can go directly to explore it with your favorite file manager.

Comment: hi Izzy , i try mount command but there is /dev/sda1 but not sda2 .

Comment: That was not clear from your question. It could very well be that the remaining disk space is not even formatted (i.e. has no file system) -- again, your question gives no clue to that. Maybe you add a few more details, e.g. which device it is, which Android version, etc.?

Comment: It;s android 4.0 version . Then why it show sda1,sda2 on running command .If it's un-partition how we partition it ?

Comment: I did not say "un-partition", but sda2 might have no file system (and thus cannot be mounted). Plus you still missed to name your device. Is it a phone, tablet, or x86?

Comment: it's x86 (having android 4.0 o.s), if sda2 have no file system how it mount ? how we access that space ?

Comment: If it has no file system, you must create one first. But I cannot tell if that's the case, it's just an assumption. You could try to mount it: Create an empty directory, and try mounting `sda2` there: `mkdir /sda2 && mount /dev/sda2 /sda2`. This might fail either when `sda2` has no file system, or when `mount` could not figure out the file system type used. Btw: I'd suggest you edit your question and add some of the facts from the comments: e.g. the output of the `mount` command for `/dev/sda*` (I just added the x68 tag for you).

Comment: Is the device inode missing? `mknod /dev/sda2 b 8 2` maybe to generate it?

Comment: @Izzy i have edit my question & thks for adding tag.

Comment: You're welcome. Based on your edit: `sda2` is a Linux partition, as is `sda1`. If there's a file system on it, it most likely is the same, too (`ext3`) -- so you could try `mkdir /sda2 && mount -t ext3 /dev/sda2` (as root, of course). If that yields an error ("wrong filesystem" or the like), try again without the `-t ext3`. If that ends up with something like "unable to determine file system", there probably is none -- in this case, `mkfs.ext3` can be used to create one (if `ext3` is fine with you -- if not, there are more `mkfs.*` commands available).

Comment: on running the command in android terminal as super user i.e mkdir /sda2 , i got : it failed said read only file system , also unable to chmod .

Comment: Any one help me ....

Comment: Without being root, you cannot a) create directories directly in `/` (you noted: read-only, so you would need to remount it) b) mount other file systems will also mostly fail (so you need to make sure to run those commands as root).

Comment: i think it's rooted that why i can access as super user mode (su). I also research in that laptop and find that  there is some other OS (MeeGo)been installed ,but not working and have to option seen in boot menu.While using bootable ubuntu usb stick ,it show two partition and one have android and  another MeeGo. Can we access ?